# Nodejs express prisma-session-store error when delete sessions from user

Tags: session, nest

I use passport with express session and for store session i use prisma session store.After block user i delete all session from him in database. After that i got this error:

```
Invalid this.prisma[this.sessionModelName].update() invocation in
/app/node_modules/@quixo3/prisma-session-store/dist/lib/prisma-session-store.js:617:81

  614 existingSession = _b.sent();
  615 if (!(existingSession !== null)) return [3 /*break*/, 5];
  616 existingSessionData = __assign(__assign({}, this.serializer.parse((_a = existingSession.data) !== null && _a !== void 0 ? _a : '{}')), { cookie: session.cookie });
→ 617 return [4 /*yield*/, this.prisma[this.sessionModelName].update(
An operation failed because it depends on one or more records that were required but not found. Record to update not found.
node:internal/errors:496
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:648:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:174:12)

    at ServerResponse.json (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:278:15)
    at CustomExceptionFilter.catch (/app/dist/src/common/filters/custom-exception.filter.js:42:30)
    at ExceptionsHandler.invokeCustomFilters (/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/exceptions/exceptions-handler.js:30:26)
    at ExceptionsHandler.next (/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/exceptions/exceptions-handler.js:14:18)
    at /app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:25:35
    at Layer.handle_error (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}` 
Any idea why?

How to avoid this error? What is reason
```

Comment: Could you share the code that leads to the error?